# Use template html file for other html files

Tags: html

Is there any way to have an html file use a "template" html file, as in having something like this as a template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="navbar"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in each file be able to change what appears in the "content" div or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an HTML file using a template file containing HTML.

To create an HTML template file:

1. Set the HTTP Content Type property to "HTML".
2. Click the Create button following the Template property.
3. Click the View button following the Template property to see the template.

You can manually create a template file by creating an empty .html file on your personal computer, entering HTML text like that below, and saving the file to your personal computer.

You can also view [this](https://help.appsheet.com/en/articles/2848415-creating-and-saving-a-file-from-a-workflow-rule-or-scheduled-report#:%7E:text=see%20the%20template.-,You%20can%20manually%20create%20a%20template%20file%20by%20creating%20an,file%20to%20your%20personal%20computer.&text=Once%20the%20template%20file%20is%20saved%20to%20you%20personal%20computer,Box) for further help.